# how to make file_put_contents create random file

Tags: php

can i make

```
file_put_contents
```

Create the file name?!

This is my code

```
file_put_contents('./v/myFile6.txt', $data);
```

but every time $data update the myFile6.txt by Replacing not add to the past lines!

So is there a way that make the file_put_contents create random names .txt and save the contents in it?!

or updating without replace the past"old" Lines?!

Like That

Old Lines

```
John
Smith
```

New Data Entries

```
Maja
```

I Want the Outlook being

```
John
Smith
Maja
```

Comment: Short answer: No. You cannot.

Comment: I Cannot doint the any way from Both?! No Random Names Or Just Add the new Entries Without Delete the old one?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [file\_put\_contents in php Bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976508/file-put-contents-in-php-bug)

Comment: If your question gets closed you do not start another question about the same issue. You edit and improve your old question so that it may be re-opened.

Comment: @crypticツ Let's be honest: that *never* works. No-one ever comes back to reopen it or cancel out the downvotes, and you can try flagging it for the mods and they don't help either. Posting a new question is the only practical thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To append the content, use `FILE_APPEND` flag.

<sup>`LOCK_EX` is using to acquire an exclusive lock on the file while proceeding to the writing.</sup>

```
file_put_contents('./v/myFile6.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: it's didn't add the new entries

Comment: @user3344662 There must be some missed point, could you show your code?

Comment: you need to check your code because this should work, see http://php.net/file_put_contents

Comment: Sorry i just Entires both $data in wrong lines

But it's working thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

use `string tempnam ( string $dir , string $prefix )` for a unique file name,
if you want to give your filename random just put variable on your filename.txt and give random value  `rand ( void )`

Comment: $dir = my folder dir

$prefix is?!

Comment: Sorry am just newbie at php coding :p